# Parse binary XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, binary

I've read the sample which parses `binary XML` as asset. It works well allowing to parse a `binary XML` included into the `APK` itself.
But I cannot parse an `arbitrary XML` read from `SD card` or so.

For asset it uses `XmlResourceParser` which correctly parses `binary XML` asset. 
For an `arbitrary` file I tried to use `XmlPullParser` which works well for text based `XML` but fails with a `binary` one.

is it possible to parse `binary XML` in `Android`?

Thanks.

Comment: "Binary XML"? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean compiled (or should i said serialized?). Like AndroidManifest.XML inside APK.

Comment: take a look at http://code.google.com/p/android4me/source/browse/src/android/content/res/ AXmlResourceParser looks like you need